# Drop down menu doesn't work after moved the header to another file

Tags: html, drop-down-menu

So I have this drop-down menu which has 7 columns. Everything worked just great till I decided to move all the header to a different file and include it from there.

Almost everything is working now great but one column that refuse to work.

Anyone familiar with the problem? Any ideas what should I check?

Thank you! :)

Comment: Check the file is linking correctly and also check dev tools that the elements are getting the styles you've applied, if not diagnose from there.

Comment: You could start posting your code, so it is easier for us to help you with your problem :)